Combine table columns into one unique value (as input for HASHBYTES)
Objective
I want to combine the four columns of a row into one value, named COMBINED_VALUE.
These strict rules apply:

Two rows with the same column values in the same order must produce the same COMBINED_VALUE
No two different rows may produce the same COMBINED_VALUE
Order of columns makes a difference, trailing spaces make a difference, invisible characters make a difference, any difference makes a difference
All columns are nullable, one columns is defined as INT, three columns are defined as NVARCHAR(100)

Notes
Among the first things I tried was BINARY_CHECKSUM. It fails, resulting in the same value for different rows:
SELECT
    a, b,
    binary_checksum_failing = BINARY_CHECKSUM(a,b)
FROM
    (VALUES ('i01', CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2), 100)),
            ('i01', CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2), 10)),
            ('i01', CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),  1)) )v(a, b)

HASHBYTES with 'SHA2_256' works better, but it needs one well prepared COMBINED_VALUE as input. If that is ensured, it has a chance to produce "very" unique hashes. I found that concatenating the columns should work but NULLs need to be replaced and columns need to be separated.
Find below two pieces of code showing my current progress and further notes. The first part shows a solution based on conversion to NVARCHAR, the second part uses VARBINARY. The example rows show edge cases and try to provoke failure.
Questions

Can you make the presented scripts fail? Can you create two different rows, that produce the same COMBINED_VALUE while passing validation?
Is there a better way to get COMBINED_VALUE? Is there a faster way? What is best practise in general?

Script #1:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t

CREATE TABLE #t
(
    id           INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR(100)
    ,number      INT
    ,word1       NVARCHAR(100)
    ,word2       NVARCHAR(100)
    ,word3       NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #t(DESCRIPTION, number, word1, word2, word3)
VALUES
 ('base row'                          , 1,        'aa',        'aa',     'aa') 
,('trailing space in different places', 1,        'aa',        'aa',    'aa ') 
,('trailing space in different places', 1,        'aa',       'aa ',     'aa') 
,('NULLs in different places'         , 1,       NULL,         'aa',     'aa') 
,('NULLs in different places'         , 1,        'aa',        NULL,     'aa') 
,('different rows, screwery with NULL', 1,        'aa',        'aa',     NULL) 
,('different rows, screwery with NULL', 1,        'aa',        'aa', '*NULL*') 
,('different rows, screwery with sep.', 1, 'aa'       , 'aa/SEP\aa',     'aa') 
,('different rows, screwery with sep.', 1, 'aa/SEP\aa',        'aa',     'aa') 
,('longer values'
  , 1111111111, 'abcdefghijklmn', 'abcdefghijklmn', 'abcdefghijklmn') 


DECLARE 
    @NULL_replacement NVARCHAR(10) = '*NULL*'
    ,@separator       NVARCHAR(10) = '/SEP\'

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
        id, DESCRIPTION, number,
        word1, word2, word3,
        COMBINED_VALUE,
        valid_f
    FROM 
        #t
    OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT valid_f = IIF(COUNT(*) = 0, 1, 0)
         FROM (VALUES  (word1)
                      ,(word2)
                      ,(word3) )v(v)
         JOIN (VALUES  (@NULL_replacement)
                      ,(@separator       ) )w(w)
           ON v LIKE '%' + w + '%' COLLATE Czech_BIN2 
        )validator
    OUTER APPLY 
        (SELECT COMBINED_VALUE = CONCAT_WS(
              @separator
              ,COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), number), @NULL_replacement) 
              ,COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), word1 ), @NULL_replacement) 
              ,COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), word2 ), @NULL_replacement) 
              ,COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), word3 ), @NULL_replacement)) 
        )combiner
)
SELECT
    id
    ,DESCRIPTION
    ,number
    ,word1_encapsulated          = '>' + word1 + '<'
    ,word2_encapsulated          = '>' + word2 + '<'
    ,word3_encapsulated          = '>' + word3 + '<'
    ,COMBINED_VALUE_encapsulated = '>' + COMBINED_VALUE + '<'
    ,valid_f
    ,repeats
    ,COMBINED_VALUE_dlen = DATALENGTH(COMBINED_VALUE)
FROM
    cte o
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT repeats = COUNT(*) 
     FROM cte i
     WHERE o.COMBINED_VALUE LIKE i.COMBINED_VALUE COLLATE Czech_BIN2 
    )repeatfinder
ORDER BY 
    id

I consider the example above proof that I need to replace NULLs and use a separator. See rows 4 and 5, if these columns get concatenated with CONCAT, you get the same output. See the column DESCRIPTION for more details.
NULL replacement and separator

Prevent different rows forming the same COMBINED_VALUE
Must be disallowed as part of input. This must be verified, input must be sanitized
Should very unlikely be part of input, should be "rare"

Script #2
After the above I came up with this mostly similar query that uses VARBINARY to make the output smaller, particularly for numeric data. Null replacement and separator are "super rare". The ASCII codes for them are labeled "unused" in the ASCII table.
DECLARE 
    @separator_bin VARBINARY(5) = 
      CONVERT(VARBINARY(5), CHAR(129)+CHAR(141)+CHAR(143)+CHAR(144)+CHAR(157))
    ,@NULL_repl_bin VARBINARY(5) = 
      CONVERT(VARBINARY(5), CHAR(157)+CHAR(144)+CHAR(143)+CHAR(141)+CHAR(129))

DECLARE 
    @separator_vc  VARCHAR(10) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @separator_bin, 2)
    ,@NULL_repl_vc VARCHAR(10) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @NULL_repl_bin, 2)

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
        id, DESCRIPTION, number,
        word1, word2, word3,
        COMBINED_VALUE, 
        valid_f, word1_binary
    FROM 
        #t
    OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT 
             number_binary = CONVERT(VARBINARY(8000), number)
             ,word1_binary = CONVERT(VARBINARY(8000), word1 )
             ,word2_binary = CONVERT(VARBINARY(8000), word2 )
             ,word3_binary = CONVERT(VARBINARY(8000), word3 )
        )binaries
    OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT valid_f = IIF(COUNT(*) = 0, 1, 0)
         FROM (VALUES  (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), number_binary, 2))
                      ,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), word1_binary , 2))
                      ,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), word2_binary , 2))
                      ,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), word3_binary , 2)) )v(v)
         JOIN (VALUES  (@separator_vc)
                      ,(@NULL_repl_vc) )w(w) 
           ON CHARINDEX(w, v COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2) > 0
        )validator
    OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT COMBINED_VALUE = 
                            COALESCE(number_binary, @NULL_repl_bin) 
         + @separator_bin + COALESCE(word1_binary , @NULL_repl_bin) 
         + @separator_bin + COALESCE(word2_binary , @NULL_repl_bin) 
         + @separator_bin + COALESCE(word3_binary , @NULL_repl_bin) 
        )combiner
    )
    SELECT
        id
        ,DESCRIPTION
        ,number
        ,word1_encapsulated = '>' + word1 + '<'
        ,word2_encapsulated = '>' + word2 + '<'
        ,word3_encapsulated = '>' + word3 + '<'
        ,COMBINED_VALUE
        ,valid_f
        ,repeats
        ,COMBINED_VALUE_dlen = DATALENGTH(COMBINED_VALUE)
        ,word1_varchar       = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), word1_binary, 2)
        ,separator_varchar   = @separator_varchar
    FROM 
        cte o
    OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT repeats = COUNT(*) 
         FROM cte i
         WHERE o.COMBINED_VALUE = i.COMBINED_VALUE
        )repeatfinder
    ORDER BY 
        id


"Can you make the presented scripts fail?" Only using contrived cases having values that contain the selected delimiter strings as you demonstrated with your  "screwery" examples. "Is there a better way to get COMBINED_VALUE?" Yes, by keeping length and null indicators separate (out-of-band) from the data, this eliminating the need for magic strings as delimiters or null-value indicators.

@TN And - to emphasize the main point - no need for sanitization of the input. Great answer!

I guess the real question is why you are using HASHBYTES on multiple columns. Are you trying to pre-empt the storage engine by rolling your own hash index? If so SHA256 is probably overkill anyway, and you'd still need to check the actual column values to be sure of a match.

@Charlieface  I can not use the hash as an identifier for rows?

You could, but why would you? It has a risk of collisions, and isn't usually more performant than just using a normal primary key across multiple columns. Or use a surrogate IDENTITY primary key. You haven't shown your use case of what you are actually trying to do with these hashes, or why normal constraints aren't enough.

I do this regularly for delta analysis with a persited computed column along this line: [ContentHash]  AS (CONVERT([binary](32),hashbytes('SHA2_256',concat(N'',col1,col2,col3)))) PERSISTED,. The starting N'' would force this to be two-byte string. Of course, you can use any kind of ÌSNULL or CASE or CONVERT to enforece a specific replacement of values.

tiny addition: You might add a separator to avoid "aaa/bb/c" produce the same hash as "aa/ab/bc". btw: Concat is very robust with data types.

@GottfriedLesigang Same here, I use something like this all the time, just trying to make it un-attackable and optimize it here. Also, you should add a NULL replacement. And using data type BINARY makes it cheaper. And you should get DATALENGTH into the mix. After all this you don't need a separator. You should propably - no guarantees from me - use the method of the approved answer by @T N.

I could suggest a binary concatenation that includes a combination of following for each column:

A null indicator IIF(col IS NULL THEN 0x01, 0x00),
The data length ISNULL(CAST(DATALENGTH(col) AS VARBINARY(MAX)), 0x), and
The value itself ISNULL(CAST(col AS VARBINARY(MAX)), 0x).

The null indicator and data length parts can be selectively omitted for non-nullable and fixed-length column types, respectively.
This will unambiguously handle any combination of nullable and variable-length columns, and you don't need to worry about delimiters in your data.
The concatenated result can be fed into a good hash function like SHA-256. The chance of a SHA-256 collision is about 1 every 10 billion years, if you add a million unique rows to your database every femtosecond.
SELECT
    t.*,
    --C.CombinedValue,
    H.HashValue
FROM #t t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
        + IIF(number IS NULL, 0x01, 0x00)
          + ISNULL(CAST(DATALENGTH(number) AS VARBINARY(MAX)), 0x) -- Optional
          + ISNULL(CAST(number AS VARBINARY(MAX)), 0x)
        + IIF(word1 IS NULL, 0x01, 0x00)
          + ISNULL(CAST(DATALENGTH(word1) AS VARBINARY(MAX)), 0x)
          + ISNULL(CAST(word1 AS VARBINARY(MAX)), 0x)
        + IIF(word2 IS NULL, 0x01, 0x00)
          + ISNULL(CAST(DATALENGTH(word2) AS VARBINARY(MAX)), 0x)
          + ISNULL(CAST(word2 AS VARBINARY(MAX)), 0x)
        + IIF(word3 IS NULL, 0x01, 0x00)
          + ISNULL(CAST(DATALENGTH(word3) AS VARBINARY(MAX)), 0x)
          + ISNULL(CAST(word3 AS VARBINARY(MAX)), 0x)
        AS CombinedValue
) C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',C.CombinedValue) AS HashValue
) H
ORDER BY T.id

The above can be easily rearranged to use a CTE if desired.
Sample results:



id
DESCRIPTION
number
word1
word2
word3
HashValue




1
base row
1
aa
aa
aa
0xFB9299EC58E4DAC1465BD3025517F735DC140BFE1CB8EE1F627C610514DF2A2D


2
trailing space in different places
1
aa
aa
aa
0x6E462C1EF5F7CD583F74F10594CFF454C6EAD556D42564153C1F9B558ECB3C3A


3
trailing space in different places
1
aa
aa
aa
0x862F08AC15AFEF147455038FF9F3AFFEB95826530BFE3DA2C87EBB8AFDAAA572


4
NULLs in different places
1
null
aa
aa
0xBDF6691C3F2207B854251CBC5A527E9A1DAFF7282F68843F97178E47A2A91900


5
NULLs in different places
1
aa
null
aa
0xB53C88CA610E62159C942AF39D61165ECDB12F52E0B65D62A126BB69257AD316


6
different rows, screwery with NULL
1
aa
aa
null
0x86D4A0F8808C4691E121001E199AD69160283768824BE86723AEE191FC5387A3


7
different rows, screwery with NULL
1
aa
aa
NULL
0x27CDC248AEDB67EA3FEE935FB28FFD6F8BCF144D0B177824DAEEA7D5F2C69D2F


8
different rows, screwery with sep.
1
aa
aa/SEP\aa
aa
0x3CD630032648215DD6AFACE7098AE0A3DCA13D8180490B99046195F1B84CAE84


9
different rows, screwery with sep.
1
aa/SEP\aa
aa
aa
0x507C17CE4F560775AE6A0973A5BB33A8E30C52160927C7D682914446AC7ADC1E


10
longer values
1111111111
abcdefghijklmn
abcdefghijklmn
abcdefghijklmn
0x04DD3801CEBEC074D512AFDA327CDB1F05089E53EE2CD93AC72BC260145A95DC



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

I only saw your answer after posting mine. Yours is better. :-)

Any particular reason for the MAX? 8000 just a fine?

The above code is designed for the general case, including a wide variety of types and a combined binary data length that potentially exceeds 8000 bytes.  In your case, VARBINARY(8000) should work, but I don't think there would be any measurable performance difference.

Great answer, great concept. I also like @Thorsten's general idea, but this one does the job and is efficient. Also, avoids checking each field for disallowed content.

@Der U: Then please consider accepting this answer instead of mine. :-)

@ThorstenKettner Oh, wow, I had. And then I accepted yours as well. To have both accepted. Which you can't. Which I now remembered. Duh...

As far as I know, you can store any binary value in an NVARCHAR character. If you have an NVARCHAR2(100) and you want some value uniquely representing that string, you need as many bytes as the original string including space for storing its length. It makes no sense to somehow convert this string when you end up with as much space anyway, as you are not after some encryption.
This means that concatenating your values is the way to go.

For each string: 100 characters (filled up with some value, e.g. a blank) plus three characters for the length from 0 to 100 and a code like 999 for NULL.
For the integer 11 characters using trailing zeros. Some magic number for NULL, e.g. 99999999999.

With SQL Server being probably the worst DBMS when it comes to casting and formatting, this gets a bit clumsy. I think this is it:
SELECT
  LEFT(COALESCE(str1, '') + REPLICATE(' ', 100), 100) +
  RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 3) + CAST(COALESCE(LEN(str1 + 'x') - 1, 999) AS NVARCHAR(3)), 3) +
  LEFT(COALESCE(str2, '') + REPLICATE(' ', 100), 100) +
  RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 3) + CAST(COALESCE(LEN(str2 + 'x') - 1, 999) AS NVARCHAR(3)), 3) +
  LEFT(COALESCE(str3, '') + REPLICATE(' ', 100), 100) +
  RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 3) + CAST(COALESCE(LEN(str3 + 'x') - 1, 999) AS NVARCHAR(3)), 3) +
  CASE WHEN int1 < 0 THEN '-' WHEN int1 > 0 THEN '+' ELSE ' ' END +
  COALESCE(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 11) + CAST(ABS(int1) AS NVARCHAR(11)), 11), '99999999999') AS code
FROM mytable;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/zR5QshZg

I like the general idea of this approach. The output has always the same length. I don't fully understand the treament of 'int1', but it still seems to me that (while not topmost efficient) this gets the job done well.

@Der U: Thank you. I format int1 with a leading sign +/- and then leading zeros. In PostgreSQL and Oracle this would simply be COALESCE(TO_CHAR(int1, 'S00000000000'), ' 99999999999').

Meanwhile I got it, you enforce the sign, also for positive numbers, and a space for zeroes. Good news: SELECT FORMAT(COALESCE(int1, 99999999999), '+00000000000;-00000000000; 00000000000'), (take note of the space.)

@Der U: That is good to know. I had looked up FORMAT and just did it again. I don't find "0" in the list of documented format specifiers. Seems to be well hidden or even undocumented.

Just checked myself, found that .NET rules apply Custom numeric format strings. The zero seems well documented. I didn't know this to this degree of certainty. I just tried some day and found a similar behaviour to Excel's cell formatting. Particularly that you can format differently for three "ranges" is very similar.
